# Display a button based on the value of the column kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

i have column named type and its an enum

```
public enum CalcEnum
    {
        Created = 0,
        Calculated = 1,
        Imported = 2,
        Edited = 3
    }
```

I want to display a button based on the value of this field. Say if the value is created then i want to show a button in the grid. I have tried like this but its not working

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.values)
    .Name("Grid1")

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
columns.Bound(p => p.UserComments).Title("Comments");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Type).Title("Type");
        columns.Template(@<text></text>)
    .ClientTemplate("#if(Type == '0') {#"
                + "<a href=\"View?TaskID=#FileID#\">View</a>"
                + "#} else {#"
                + "<a href=\"Open?TaskID=#FileID#\">Open</a>"
                + "#} #").Title(string.Empty);
    }
```

Any clues where im doing wrong ?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the [templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) overview. 
Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258083/kendo-grid-column-with-conditionally-chosen-action) where an external function is called to do all the processing. 
Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786962/conditionals-embedded-in-client-templates-in-kendo-ui-mvc-grid-server) to yours.

I am also not too sure why you have quotes on your 0.
I have performed the action client side and if you do this I believe you need to put 'data.' before your Model's property.

```
`#if(data.Type == 0)`
```

Try that OR check the links below to see the links to questions similar to yours.

I can't set up a project to test this at the moment but I can give you a quick look at how I have used it with a boolean (CanCanel).

```
 columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(
                                         "<button type='button' class='myRequestsViewRequest grid-btn grid-btn-primary' style='margin: 3px 15px 3px 0;'" +
                                         "data-requestid='#= RequestId #' data-requesterdisplayname='#= RequesterDisplayName #'>View</button>" +
                                         " #if (!(data.CanCancel)) " +
                                         "{# <span class='grid-btn grid-btn-disabled'>Cancel</span> #} " +
                                         "else {# <a class='grid-btn grid-btn-primary' href='" +
                                         Url.Action("CancelRequest", "Home") +
                                         "?requestId=#= RequestId #' " +
                                         " onclick='return MyRequest_ConfirmCancel()'>Cancel</a> #}#")
          .Title("Actions")
          .Width(200);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the column value 'Type' in the condition as below

```
if(#=Type# == '0')
```